# rails: use jbuilder template in various controller methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

Is it possible to reuse jbuilder-template in another controller method? In other words: how to explicitly say controller method to use concrete jbuilder-template?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From [`Rails guide`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html).

#### Rendering an Action's Template from Another Controller.

> What if you want to render a template from an entirely different
>   controller from the one that contains the action code? You can also do
>   that with render, which accepts the full path (relative to app/views)
>   of the template to render. For example, if you're running code in an
>   AdminProductsController that lives in app/controllers/admin, you can
>   render the results of an action to a template in app/views/products
>   this way

```
def my_action
  # some code here
  render "products/show"
end
```

Comment: didn't think that this propagates to jbuilder, thank you green man

Answer (score 9):

```
def my_action
  # some code here
  render "products/show.json"
end
```

or

```
def my_action
  # some code here
  render "show.json"
end
```

without the .json it will try to render an html file.